# How to specify Mockito mock extraInterfaces in Kotlin (using nhaarman mockitokotlin2)

Tags: kotlin, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I understand how to specify extraInterface using the `@Mock` annotation, but how can I create a mock and add the `extraInterfaces` inline?

```
@SmallTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MyTestClass {
    
    @Mock(extraInterfaces = [MyCallback::class])
    lateinit var callbackFragment: Fragment
    ...
}
```

But how can I do this on the fly?

```
// this doesn't compile
val callbackFragment = mock<Fragment>(extraInterfaces = [MyCallback::class])
```

What is the correct syntax for adding `extraInterfaces` to a Mockito mock in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
 val mock = mock<Fragment>(extraInterfaces = arrayOf(MyCallback::class))
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
@Mock(extraInterfaces = [MyCallback::class])
lateinit var fragment: Fragment
```